# Access the firebaseUser 'created' timestamp from within javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, firebase-authentication, angularfire

I'm wanting to read the 'Created' timestamp (that is available in the Authentication > USERS section of the Firebase console) directly from the firebaseUser object within the run function of my Angular app using AngularFire.

e.g

```
FirebaseAuth.$onAuthStateChanged(function(firebaseUser) {
    console.log(firebaseUser.created)
}
```

Is a timestamp present anywhere on the object? I'm trying to avoid invoking the database at this point.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add creation date in your database when creating a new account:

```
Users
  useruid <-- from the console
     name: userx
     email: userx@gmail.com
     creationdate: 2018-02-10
  useruid
     name: usery
     email: usery@gmail.com 
     creationdate: 2018-03-01
```

Also check this:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User

*Or retrieve it using `metadata` as stated here:*

[creationTime:](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.UserMetadata#creationTime)

> The date the user was created, formatted as a UTC string. For example, 'Fri, 22 Sep 2017 01:49:58 GMT'.

*Or using the Admin SDK:*

```
admin.auth().getUser(uid).then(function(userRecord) {
console.log("Creation time:", userRecord.metadata.creationTime);
});
```

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.auth.UserMetadata

Comment: is there a way to convert the UTC format to local for creationTime?